# Не получается закрывать дженерик наследником класса с другим закрытым дженериком в .net core

Tags: c#, наследование, constraints

Допустим есть следующая иерархия:

```
public class ExampleHierarchy
{
    public interface IValue
    {}

    public abstract class ValueClassBase : IValue
    {}

    public class ValueClass : ValueClassBase
    {}

    public interface IInterface1<TValue>
        where TValue : IValue
    {
        TValue SomeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class RealizeInterface1Base<TValue> : IInterface1<TValue>
        where TValue : IValue
    {
        public TValue SomeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class RealizeInterface1 : RealizeInterface1Base<ValueClass>
    {
    }

    public interface IInterface2<TTool>
        where TTool : IInterface1<IValue>
    {
        TTool SomeTool { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class RealizeInterface2Base<TTool> : IInterface2<TTool>
        where TTool : IInterface1<IValue>
    {
        public TTool SomeTool { get; set; }
    }

    public class RealizeInterface2 : RealizeInterface2Base<RealizeInterface1>
    {
    }
}
```

Получаем следующую ошибку:

```
The type 'PokerDecisions.ExampleHierarchy.RealizeInterface1' must be convertible to 'PokerDecisions.ExampleHierarchy.IInterface1<PokerDecisions.ExampleHierarchy.IValue>' in order to use it as parameter 'TTool' in the generic class 'PokerDecisions.ExampleHierarchy.RealizeInterface2Base<TTool>'
```

Моя иерархия ещё более запутанная и сложная: у меня есть ещё одно вложенное наследование всех этих иерархий, и получается аж два неявно закрытых дженерика, а не один, как здесь.
Что меня озадачивает: класс RealizeInterface1 реализует интерфейс IInterface1 и закрывает дженерик, но он "неконвертируемый", как пишет компилятор.
Если я вместо него подставляю `RealizeInterface1Base<ValueClass>` и также с базовым `ValueClassBase`, то получу ровно ту же ошибку, однако если вместо `ValueClass` подставить `IValue`, то всё магическим образом становится конвертируемым.

```
    public class RealizeInterface2 : RealizeInterface2Base<RealizeInterface1Base<IValue>>
    {
    }
```

Делаю вывод, что ограничение в виде интерфейса, который сам является ограничением, работает как-то не совсем так, как я ожидал, но уже второй день ломаю мозги, как же будет правильно?
Очевидным кажется выход для IValue также добавить параметр типа, тогда всё вылечится, например:

```
    public interface IInterface2<TTool, TValue>
        where TTool : IInterface1<TValue>
        where TValue : IValue
    {
        TTool SomeTool { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class RealizeInterface2Base<TTool, TValue> : IInterface2<TTool, TValue>
        where TTool : IInterface1<TValue>
        where TValue : IValue
    {
        public TTool SomeTool { get; set; }
    }

    public class RealizeInterface2 : RealizeInterface2Base<RealizeInterface1, ValueClass>
    {
    }
```

Всё компилируется, все счастливы, кроме меня. Зачем мне наследник, закрывающий дженерик, если я всё равно вынужден явно смотреть, каким классом закрыт этот дженерик и явно закрывать его во всей иерархии?

Здесь это не выглядит так уж страшно, но мне нужно прошерстить пару десятков файлов и изменить ограничения, а при каждом новом файлике посмотреть из чего состоят свойства классов, которыми я закрыл верхний дженерик, и это сейчас у меня "всего" три параметра типа, а если где-то в середине объявится ещё один дженерик, нужно будет вверх по иерархии передать ещё один тип?

И ещё не нравится, что я как бы создал наследника, у которого закрыты параметры типов, и вынужден явно рядом с ним приписывать тот же тип, которым только что в нём закрыл этот параметр...

Нет ли какого-либо более изящного выхода? Или может я вообще что-то не так применяю?

Comment: Более изящный выход - задуматься об изменении структуры типов. А решается он от бизнес-задачи. Лепить дженерики ради дженериков - это ошибка проектирования. Запутанности не должно быть. Если она произошла, значит надо переосмыслить архитектуру и потребность в том, что вы делаете. Так вот, в вашем вопросе хорошо обрисована цель, а зачем эта цель в принципе преследуется - не ясно. Боюсь, на уровне абстрактного примера здесь мало чего толкового можно придумать.

Comment: Ну, то есть единственный способ избавиться от "лишних" параметров типа — это использовать конкретные типы, получается?)

Comment: Подсказка по английскому: "realize" => "implement".

Comment: Спасибо за корректировку. Вроде и знал, но английский всё ещё далёк от второго языка для меня, поэтому ошибаюсь =)

Comment: Нет, не так. Нужно определить задачу в целом, и что для нее нужно. Шарп очень гибкий в плане наследования и интерфейсов, зачастую одну и ту же бизнес-задачу можно решить множеством способов. Один из них у вас в наличии, ищите другие.

Comment: Да, в целом ясно. Просто, как обычно: хочется максимально абстрагировать все иерархии "на будущее", из-за этого теряем время "в настоящем" =)
Возможно, что до реализации того, зачем мне эти параметры типов, проект и не доживёт/не дорастёт.

Comment: Чтобы не размусоливать километровую стену комментов, переформулирую себя. Вы ищете новые, незнакомые, пропущенные в обучении технологии. Их нет, у вас все хорошо с дженериками и ограничениями. А вот с применением беда, как на самом деле - не знаю, а с виду вы явно злоупотребляете. Следовательно, нужна конкретная бизнес-задача, чтобы этот вопрос начать решать нормально. А пока этот пост - [ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567), забивание гвоздей микроскопом без объяснения причины. Быть может я спешу с выводами, но выглядит это именно так.

Comment: Пока писал уточнение с конкретизацией абстракций, решил, что один из дженериков можно убрать временно, а другой мб никогда не будет иметь потомков.
Спасибо за помощь! 
2 дня мучений получили ответ в первом комментарии и решение благодаря попытке ответить на последний =)
Извиняюсь, если я что-то не так "оформил"/"ответил"

Comment: Все так, просто сам по себе вопрос не имеет правильного, объективного ответа. Либо я его не вижу. Поэтому вместо ответа рождаются только общие рекомендации.